# Android 6 - setNeedBle(true) doesn't ask BLE to enable

Tags: android, bluetooth, permissions, location, android-permissions

On Android 6 I need to ask location permission from user and also - to enable GPS and BLE. On older version of android all was good and geo system dialog are correct (it include both gps and ble):

[image]

But on android 6 even if I have use code like this:

```
LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    builder.addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    builder.setNeedBle(true);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
```

On devices I have only GPS in system dialog (without BLE) :

[image]

That's wrong I'm doing or it is bug?